# How to output ''toto_list'' items in ''father_list'' list input, as separate list

Tags: python, list

```
def print_tidy_list(film_names):
    toto_list = ['Toto XX', 'The Seventh One', 'Fahrenheit']
    tidy_list = [x for x in film_names if toto_list in x]
    return print(tidy_list)

father_list = ["Because They're Young", "Checkmate", "Fahrenheit", "Toto XX"]
print(print_tidy_list(father_list))
```

#my goal in this example is to get ['Fahrenheit', 'Toto XX'] as output. This without using separate string items and/or lines, so basically referring to the whole list, how do I do this? Thank you

Comment: `toto_list in x` makes no sense, I guess you would wanted like this: `tidy_list = [x for x in film_names if x in toto_list]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print_tidy_list` needs to *print* or to *return* a list? `return print(tidy_list)` will give you `None`.

You should do like this, and take care of the *printing* activity outside the function:

```py
def print_tidy_list(film_names):
    toto_list = ['Toto XX', 'The Seventh One', 'Fahrenheit']
    tidy_list = [x for x in film_names if x in toto_list]
    return tidy_list
```

or you could `print(tidy_list)` in the function (as the name would suggest) and do not return anything.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to programming, I ve been breaking my brain for hours, funny that its just this little adjustment. 

Could you explain to me why you get output and 'none' when you go like: `return print(tidy_list)`, instead of `return tidy_list?`

Comment: @vedadhadzic the `return tidy_list` - as assume - is self explanatory. `print` is a function which essentially *shows* the string representation of the passed argument (in this case, a list) and does nothing else. In python, not having a `return` is equivalent to `return None`.